# Does such a dilation exist?

Tags: geometry

Is there a composition of dilatations and isometries that transforms the set $\bigcup_{n}S(0,1/n)$ to $\bigcup_{n}S(n,1/n)$, and leave everything else invariant? Here $S(a,r)$ is the sphere of center $a$ and radius $r>0$ and the sets are in $ \mathbb{R}^{m} $ with $m>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what $n$ is supposed to vary over in your notation $\bigcup_{n}$, but let me assume that it varies over the positive integers $n=1,2,3,...$

In that case the first set $\bigcup_{n} S(0,\frac{1}{n})$
is bounded, whereas the second set $\bigcup_{n} S(n,\frac{1}{n})$ is unbounded.

Since dilations and isometries each take bounded sets to bounded sets, the image of a bounded set under any composition of dilations and isometries is also a bounded set. Hence the first set cannot be mapped to the second set.